# how to overwrite the data in hive using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to load data into an already existing table in hive via sqoop from mysql database. I am referring to the below guide for reference:-
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive

`--hive-import` has been tried and tested successfully.

I created a hive table as below:-

1. `create table sqoophive (id int, name string, location string)
   row format delimited
   fields terminated by '\t'
   lines terminated by '\n'
   stored as textfile;`
2. Loaded the data as required.
3. I want to use `--hive-overwrite` option to overwrite the content in the above table. As per the guide mentioned above - "--hive-overwrite    Overwrite existing data in the Hive table."

"If the Hive table already exists, you can specify the --hive-overwrite option to indicate that existing table in hive must be replaced."

So I tried the below queries separately to get the result:-

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password 'hr' --table sample --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table sqoophive -m 1 --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n'`

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password 'hr' --table sample --hive-overwrite --hive-table sqoophive -m 1 --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n'`

but rather than replacing the content in the existing table it just created a file in the below path `/user/<username>/<mysqltablename>`

Can somebody please explain me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the first query should work fine. I didn't give fields terminated and lines terminated as the schema already exists.

the keywords `--hive-import` and `--hive-overwrite` should be there.

if only `--hive-overwrite` is there, it doesn't load data to the table. just copies to hdfs.

Answer (score 1):

`sqoop import` with out `--target-dir` OR `--warehouse-dir` (for `--hive-import`) will import `/user/<username>/<mysqltablename>`:

> [By default](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_import_process), Sqoop will import a table named `foo` to a directory named
>   `foo` inside your home directory in HDFS. For example, if your username
>   is `someuser`, then the import tool will write to
>   `/user/someuser/foo/(files)`. You can adjust the parent directory of the
>   import with the `--warehouse-dir` argument.
>
> You can also explicitly choose the target directory with `--target-dir` param

but as [@hrobertv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4375921/hrobertv) said that `--hive-overwrite` does not delete existing dir but it overwrites the HDFS data location of  hive table. if you want to save new data at same location as origin than you would have to delete the existing table dir first and then run sqoop import with specifying `--target-dir` OR `--warehouse-dir` for `--hive-overwrite` to store data at specific location as per your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

It's putting the _SUCCESS file in

```
/user/<username>/<mysqltablename>
```

You can change where that goes with --warehouse-dir 
ex: --warehouse-dir /tmp

One would think that hive-overwrite would handle this, meaning remove that directory first. But for good reason Hive doesn't want to start removing dirs in HDFS. What if something else was put in there?

hive-overwrite is saying, "I'm going to overwrite the rows in Hive, not just add to the table." Thus you will not have duplicates.

You have to remove that directory and the _SUCCESS file first; or better yet, right after the import is successful.

```
 hadoop fs -rm -R /user/<username>/<mysqltablename>
```